# Assigning text color to text in EditText

Tags: android, android-widget

How do I assign a different color to text in EditText by extending it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use spans:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("partial colored text");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: Is `setText` missing a parameter? I think it also takes a `BufferType`.

Answer (score 27):

you can change the text color by adding `android:textColor` like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#f00" />
```

Answer (score 8):

I had problems with using textColor attribute in style.xml file:

```
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

For me editTextColor works :

```
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a very old question but since this was the first I got while searching, I would like to add an answer so that future readers get them.

We can create our own custom style in styles.xml file with many other attributes in addition to textColor and apply to our EditText.

Add this in styles.xml,

```
<style name="MyEditTextstyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_custom_edittext_bg</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    //many more per requirement
</style>
```

And then simply apply this style to the EditText as,

```
<EditText
    style="@style/MyEditTextstyle" //here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Item Name"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Simple, right. :) Important part is we can apply the same stuff to any more EditText's if needed. :)

Answer (score 5):

To change it programatically, add a color in your colors.xml file

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorText">#424242</color>
```

and reference it like this:

```
myEditText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorText));
```

Answer (score 2):

**From XML Layout :**

We can change `EditText` text color by adding `android:textColor` as below :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your Name"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
</EditText>
```

---

**From Java Class :**

We can change `EditText` text color pragmatically by adding method `EditText.setTextColor()` as below :

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 1):

android:textColor, set this property in EditText xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="what_ever_size"
  android:layout_height="what_ever_size"
  android:textColor="@color/your_choice_of_color" />
```