# Why does the Xamarin equivalent of EditText.getText() return a string?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm a new Xamarin.Android developer. I was reading through some Java code recently that used `EditText` methods in a derived class. One of the derived class' methods looked like this:

```
private void checkMatchingBracket(int paramInt)
{
    getText().removeSpan(this.openBracketSpan);
    getText().removeSpan(this.closeBracketSpan);
    ...
}
```

This confused me because I thought `getText()` returned a `String`, as the `EditText.Text` property is a `string` in this class' Xamarin counterpart. However, this is not the case; it appears that `getText()` returns an [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html), which looks like a mutable string type that offers additional functionality such as attaching 'spans' to certain regions of text ([`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)?). My guess is that the `string` Xamarin returns has been copied over from the text of this `Editable`, so I can't really modify the original `Editable` and use its APIs.

Am I correct? Is it not possible to get access to the original `Editable` here because I'm using Xamarin?

**edit:** The specific thing I'm looking to do is color regions of the text in an `EditText`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242512/4077294) which uses spans to achieve this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("partial colored text");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

However, Xamarin's API `EditText.Text.set` only accepts a .NET `string`, which obviously has no notion of color or 'spans'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `EditableText` property:

```
var editable = aTextView.EditableText;
editable?.RemoveSpan(aSpanObject);
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.TextView.EditableText/

> Return the text the TextView is displaying as an Editable object. If the text is not editable, null is returned.