# How to set autocomplete text inside EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I have an EditText. when i type something, i do a DB query based on the typed string and show the results in a recycler view. i want to show the first result item from the query result in the edit text itself in grey colour. For eg.

I type "sa"

Results are shown as :

"saaa"
"sab"
"sacc"

i want that once the result are fetched, Edit text should show first item:
"sa|aa"

here "sa" will be in black colour, then cursor , then aa will be in grey colour.

so the user gets the autocomplete kind of feel.

The problem i am facing is , how i set the text on edit text with two different strings both of different colours. I tried setting both text and hint, looks like hint does not work when text is set.
Whats the proper way to do it ?

Comment: see `ForegroudColorSpan`

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242274/assigning-text-color-to-text-in-edittext) for general understanding. Check the developer website for in-depth knowledge about [Spans](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans)

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder("Text is spantastic!");
spannable.setSpan(
    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
    8, // start
    12, // end
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
);
```

[image: Sample Output for Spannable]