# Is there a way I can change the text color of an editText on encountering a word from a string array?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to implement something similar to a code editor where keywords are automatically highlighted. I am going to have a string array and I want to change the color and font of the editText string when the user types the text and it matches a string from the string array. I am using the addTextChangeListener but the text of the whole editText changes. I want just the matched word to be highlighted. Here is my code:

```
inputCodeEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().contains("for"))
            {
                inputCodeEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo));
            }
        }
    });

I understand I have to use spans but the code crashes. Can anyone help me with the correct usage of spannable strings with addTextChangedListener() ?
```

Comment: In the event handler for typing of the text edit widget, you may use `String#contains` or `String#matches` to detect the trigger string, then change the text color based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use addTextChangeListener API eg:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // The changed text comes in "s" parameter.
                // Here you can watch the changes and take an action you want...
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Take a look at here, same issue wit textview -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242274/assigning-text-color-to-text-in-edittext